# How to change BorderColor of a TextBox using CSS, when user clicks on it (ASP.NET)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, colors, textbox

[image]Morning All

Although I am able to change the `BorderColor` of a `<asp:Textbox>` through `CSS`, I am currently wondering why such attempt fails once a user clicks on the `Textbox` (e.g. a default `BorderColor` persists).

```
<style type="text/css">

.txt{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color:#cfd1d4;
}
.txt:hover{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #cfd1d4;
}
.txt:focus{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #cfd1d4;
}
</style>
...
        <body>
           <form id="form1" runat="server">
              <div>
                  <asp:TextBox id="_txt_did" placeholder="this is a test case" runat ="server" 
 Width="90%" Font-Size="14px" Font-Italic="true" CssClass ="txt"></asp:TextBox>
              </div>
            </form>
       </body>
...
```

*P.S. I've added a picture for an illustration of the issue. The purpose was to keep **identical** `Textbox(es)` (benchmark being the one `PageLoad()`) even if one clicks on the `Textbox`*

Comment: Works fine. You do have the same border color for all the 3 states however.  Make then different colors and see what happens

Comment: Yep, it's working fine for me

Comment: @VDWWD : bizzare... From my side,  it works fine. Then, once you click on the textbox the highlighted bordercolor  reverts back to ```black``` (solid line) as opposed to the requested #cfd1d4

Comment: @AlexandreVelo: I have added a picture for an  illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same border-color in all of your styles just change it and try

```
<style type="text/css">

.txt{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color:#681807;
}
.txt:hover{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #07685F;
}
.txt:focus{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #68075E;
}
</style>
<html>
        <body>
           <form id="form1" runat="server">
              <div>
                  <asp:TextBox id="_txt_did" placeholder="this is a test case" runat ="server" 
 Width="90%" Font-Size="14px" Font-Italic="true" CssClass ="txt"></asp:TextBox>
              </div>
            </form>
       </body>
</html>
```